# How check value by consecutive date variable

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have database table in SNOWFLAKE, where I need check for each customer if there is FLAG_1 == 1 at minimum 3 days in row. Flag_1 indicates whether the order contained any specific goods. And create new table with customer_id and flag_2. I really don't know how to handle this problem.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TEST
(
CUSTOMER_ID INT,
ORDER_DATE DATE,
FLAG_1 INT
);


INSERT INTO TMP_TEST (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE, FLAG_1)
VALUES
  (001, '2020-04-01', 0),
  (001, '2020-04-02', 1),
  (001, '2020-04-03', 1),
  (001, '2020-04-04', 1),
  (001, '2020-04-05', 1),
  (001, '2020-04-06', 0),
  (001, '2020-04-07', 0),
  (001, '2020-04-08', 0),
  (001, '2020-04-09', 1),
  (002, '2020-04-10', 1),
  (002, '2020-04-11', 0),
  (002, '2020-04-12', 0),
  (002, '2020-04-13', 1),
  (002, '2020-04-14', 1),
  (002, '2020-04-15', 0),
  (002, '2020-04-16', 1),
  (002, '2020-04-17', 1);
```

Expected output table:

```
CUSTOMER_ID   FLAG_2
001   1
002   0
```

Comment: *consecutive date variable* Do you mean consecutive **dates** precisely, or you mean consecutive **rows** ordered by date? i.e. if there are 3 consecutive rows for days 1,2,4 (the row for day 3 is absent) with flag set does these rows matches your criteria? PS. You tell that you use Snowflake - why the question is MySQL-tagged?

Comment: Calculate SUM(flag_1 = 0) over the user ordered by date. The consecutive rows with flag set will have the same sum. Then simply check does the sum value whose count is 3 or above exists.

Comment: I mean consecutive dates precisely. 3 days in row (22.4.2022, 23.4.2022, 24.4.2022)

Comment: If so then check that either flag=0 or the date is not lag(date)+1day. You need 2 CTEs - first gets LAG(), second calculates sums (divides the rowset to consecutive groups), outer query checks does the rows pack matched exists.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Snowflake?

Comment: Im using only snowflake.

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be help:

```
with calcflag as (
select customer_id, IFF( sum(flag_1) over (PARTITION by customer_id order by order_date rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) = 3, 1, 0 ) as new_flag 
from tmp_Test)
select customer_id, max(new_flag) flag_2
from calcflag
group by 1
order by 1;

+-------------+--------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | FLAG_2 |
+-------------+--------+
|           1 |      1 |
|           2 |      0 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

using COUNT_IF also works:

```
with calcflag as (
    select 
        customer_id, 
        IFF(
            count_if(flag_1 = 1) over (
                PARTITION by customer_id 
                order by order_date 
                rows between 2 preceding and current row
            ) = 3, 1, 0
        ) as new_flag 
    from tmp_Test
)
select 
    customer_id, 
    max(new_flag) flag_2
from calcflag
group by 1

+-------------+--------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | FLAG_2 |
|-------------+--------|
|           1 |      1 |
|           2 |      0 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html#match-recognize) which is the easiest way to detect advanced patterns across multiple rows:

To find 3 or more occurences the pattern is `PATTERN ( a{3,})`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TMP_TEST
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
    ORDER BY ORDER_DATE
    MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
    PATTERN ( a{3,} )
    DEFINE a AS FLAG_1 = 1
) mr
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Collapsing to single row per group:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, COALESCE(MIN(MN),0) AS FLAG_2
FROM TMP_TEST
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
    ORDER BY ORDER_DATE
    MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
    PATTERN ( a{3,})
    DEFINE a AS FLAG_1 = 1
) mr
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Output:

[image]

---

The power of this solution lies at the PATTERN part which could be easily extended with new conditions. For instance:

```
PATTERN ( a b{1,2} a )
DEFINE a AS FLAG_1 = 1,
       b AS FLAT_2 = 0;
```

Here: Find sequence of flag = 1, followed by one or two occurences of flag = 0 and ended by flag = 1.